# Error with OkObjectResult and json string when moving from a FunctionApp to ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

I had a function app in C# that made a function call to a stored procedure and returned the results as follows:

```
 connection.Open();
 SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 var dataTable = new DataTable();
 dataTable.Load(reader);
 jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);                  
 connection.Close();
    
 return new OkObjectResult(jsonstring);
```

When I moved this code to >NET CORE I get the following error message:
CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type Microsoftaspnetcore.mvc.OkObjectResult to Microsoftaspnetcore.mvc.JsonResult

But if I switch to JsonResult(jsonstring) then my application thows this error: Error parsing JSON data: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON when I run JSON.parse(data)

I have tried different formats but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `JsonResult(jsonstring)`, you are returning the response with JSON array string as below:

```
"[/* JSON objects */]"
```

Instead of returning JSON in string, you should return the array as:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public JsonResult YourApiAction(/* arguments */)
{
    ...

    return new JsonResult(JArray.FromObject(dataTable));
}
```

Or you can return the `dataTable` directly. It will be serialized as a JSON array.

```cs
public JsonResult YourApiAction(/* arguments */)
{
    ...

    return new JsonResult(dt);
}
```

Side note, if your Controller class inherits [`Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-7.0) as the base class, you can use the [`Json` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controller-json(system-object)).

```cs
public class YourController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult YourApiAction(/* arguments */)
    {
        ...

        return Json(dt);
    }
}
```